# How to get vehicle ID and type as unique Identifier from SUMO vehicle ID

Tags: omnet++

I'm use **sumo** 0.21.0 , **omnet++** 4.6 , and **Veins** 3.0
I'm succeed in connecting my traffic mobility simulation (sumo) with network simulation (omnet++).
I have flow of vehicle route in sumo rou file,

```
 <vType accel="2.0" decel="2.0" id="CarA" length="5.0" maxSpeed="15.0" minGap="2.5" sigma="0" vClass="passenger"/>
<vType accel="2.0" color="0,1,0" decel="2.0" guiShape="bus" id="BUS" length="10" maxSpeed="12.0" minGap="2.5" sigma="0" speedDev="0.1" speedFactor="1.2" vClass="bus"/>

`<flow begin="0" id="Bus1001" period="510" type="BUS" departSpeed="12" departLane="0">
    <route edges="D1"/>
    <stop busStop="busstop1" duration="8.470000284081323"/>
</flow>
<flow begin="0" color="0,0,1" id="car0" period="30" type="CarA" departSpeed="15" departLane="1">
    <route edges="D1"/>
</flow>`
```

and have 2 types of vehicle BUS and CarA.
I want to use **sumo vehicle ID** as the nodes id in omnet++ and differentiate between vehicle car and bus.
I read about adding `getExternalId()` but I can't find any clear and detail explanation how can it works, and how can I add those code in omnet++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class [TraCIMobility](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.h) provides a function to get the external id (which is the SUMO id).

The example application [TraCIDemo11p](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc) shows how to get the mobility in your application. Then the only thing left to do is to call `traci->getExternalId()` which returns the id as a string.

*Note that this answer is for Veins 3.0. For newer version it works in a similar way.*

Comment: thank you @floxyz for your explanation  
I use the example application TraCIDemo11p and can be shown in module log that it use the sumo vehicle id like this  
  
`updatePosition:  HostMove  startPos: (35.1,29.95,1.895) direction: (1,-0,0) startTime: 1 speed: 12
Added vehicle **#Bus1001.0**`  
`updatePosition:  HostMove  startPos: (30.1,26.65,1.895) direction: (1,-0,0) startTime: 1 speed: 15
Added vehicle **#car0.0**`  
  
I just wonder where can I find the declaration of geting the ExternalId in the TraCIMobility / TraCIDemo11p.

Comment: In my answer I linked the code to the two necessary classes which provide the declarations and example code.