# How to get Vehicle ID from SUMO in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

In my Veins simulation, I want to use SUMO vehicle ID as the ID of the vehicle (instead of using Veins module id). I tried different method but was not successful.  I tried to obtain sumo id using **mobility -> getExternalId()** in DemoBaseApplLayer.cc file. Build was successful but it does not run. If i do, **getParentModule->getId()** - it works fine. But I need SUMO Id not module id for my work,

Is there a way to use SUMO vehicle Id as the id of the vehicle in Veins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781359/how-to-get-vehicle-id-and-type-as-unique-identifier-from-sumo-vehicle-id#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20class%20TraCIMobility%20provides%20a,the%20id%20as%20a%20string.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the wireless node with node vector index `1` in OMNeT++ should correspond to a vehicle named `vehicle_1` in SUMO this will not easily be possible. If all you want to do is inquire about which name SUMO uses to refer to a wireless node managed via `TraCIMobility` in OMNeT++ then its `getExternalId` method is exactly the right one to call. If using the method gives you a runtime error, please post the precise output and messages you are seeing, the precise software versions you are using, and the steps needed to reproduce your error on another machine.